# Python. Jupyter kernels stops when increasing number of lags in custom time series plot func

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I have the following code which defines a time series plot function and displays adfuller statistics

```
    def tsplot(y, lags=None, figsize=(12, 7), style='bmh'):
    if not isinstance(y, pd.Series):
        y = pd.Series(y)
    with plt.style.context(style):    
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
        layout = (2, 2)
        ts_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0, 0), colspan=2)
        acf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1, 0))
        pacf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1, 1))

        y.plot(ax=ts_ax)
        ts_ax.set_title('Time Series Analysis Plots')
        smt.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=lags, ax=acf_ax, alpha=0.5)
        smt.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=lags, ax=pacf_ax, alpha=0.5)

        print("Adfuller: p=%f" % sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(y)[1])

        plt.tight_layout()
    return 
tsplot(dataset.Users, lags=30)
```

Trying to print the plot on my data with different number of lags I faced an issue. Everything works well when lags=10, for example, when I increase the number of lags up to 30-35 Jupyter kernel shuts down (probable it doesn't, but I waited for about 20 minutes and got no result). It also worked for lags=31 and didn't for lags=32, for example. I failed to find any dependencies here. Tried to do this in Jupyter and Jupyter lab. Cannot figure out what is the problem.

Dataset contains some observations for 300 days.

I am comparatively new in time series analysis. Would appreciate any help in figuring out why this functions doesn't work when the number of lags increases.

Comment: Can you confirm the shutdown or at least monitor resource usage with your system's preferred process monitor (Task Manager on windows, Activity Monitor on mac, top on *nix)?

Comment: Will do that tomorrow morning in the office and comment it back. Don't have that notebook on my home PC.

Comment: statsmodels adfuller unfortunately keeps all results for the lag search in memory. You could try with commenting out the adfuller line and see whether it affects the memory problem. However, it doesn't depend on `lags` in your function, so I don't see anything on the statsmodels side that should use a lot of memory as a function of `lags`.